# Is there such thing as a normally closed MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, relay, integrated-circuit, surface-mount

Is there such thing as a normally closed MOSFET? Or can I somehow make a circuit?

Can I control a circuit that functions like that with a control logic voltage of 3.3 V or 5 V so that when I give a logical high the normally closed circuit changes to open?

Comment: Not really "normally closed", but P and N channel can be regarded as inverse logical functions, similar to PNP and NPN.

Comment: Sounds like a depletion (as opposed to enhancement) mosfet. Not common, and I haven’t encountered ones for power switching if that’s what you need. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depletion_and_enhancement_modes

Comment: (JFETs (junction-) are *depletion mode*.)

Comment: I have not need mosfet .I need like as  mentioned above circuit or component.

Comment: You asked about a normally closed MOSFET. As @Bryan stated above, a depletion MOSFET is normally closed.

Comment: @Bryan Please make your comment an answer.

Comment: Depletion MOSFET gate terminal is Floating How its working?

Comment: Same as regular enhancement MOSFETs but you need negative voltage to turn them off.

Comment: Depending on the circuit, you might be able to use a P-channel MOSFET.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to switch? There's usually a simple solution that doesn't require exotic devices.

Comment: I have try to short two terminal at normal condition Without any voltage. After I give logic to Open that two terminal. So I have need this type of Simple circuit and low cost.

Answer (score 17):

Depletion-mode MOSFETs conduct with zero Vgs.

N-channel devices are easily available and useful in some specialty applications such as loop-powered instrumentation. You apply a negative Vgs to turn them off, like the grid on a vacuum tube.

P-channel devices (with the possible exception of RF devices) are unavailable or close to unavailable, afaik.

Comment: I know OP asked for MOSFETS, but let's not forget JFETs.

Comment: Yes, JFETs are depletion mode and P-channel types are available.

Comment: Here is an application note that includes a few unique uses of depletion MOSFETS: [Supertex inc. AN-D66](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN-D66.pdf)

Comment: Depletion mode  MOSFET cost is Very High . So I have need Low cost and Simple Circuit like as Transistor.

Comment: @anbub if a few tens of cents is too high then you need some power source to keep the device on.

Answer (score 12):

Three transistors are "normally closed". You asked about MOSFETs, but be aware also that JFETs do that as well.

- Depletion N-channel MOSFETs (Available for high current, high voltage)
- N-channel JFETs
- P-channel JFETs

Note that:

- The N-channel devices are turned off by a gate voltage that is more negative than the source.
- The P-channel device is turned off by a gate voltage that is more positive than the source.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are called depletion mode devices and they are harder to find.